# MySQL server (MariaDB) cannot start

Tags: macos, mysql

I'm trying to start MySQL server (Maria DB 10.0.12, installed via Homebrew) but it's not working.

When I run `mysql.server start`, it keeps running forever without actually starting the server.

`mysql.server configtest` tells me the config is fine and there is nothing in MySQL error log.

I haven't actually changed anything to MySQL recently, though I've upgraded PHP and other modules (but I guess that shouldn't be related).

Any idea what could be causing this, or how to debug it?

Comment: So when you run the start command what actually happens? It just says "Starting MySQL" and gives you a seemingly endless line of "....."?

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan, yes that's correct.

Comment: And if you try `mysql.server stop` what happens?

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan, nothing as the server is not running. I've also checked `ps aux | grep mysql` and there's nothing there.

Comment: If you try to stop a MariaDB/MySQL server that isn't running you should get an error message saying "ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!". Did you get that?

Answer (score 2):

One place to start debugging this is to check for a `err` file. It will be named with the hostname of your Mac and you should find it in `/usr/local/var/mysql`. So if you Mac is called `charles` the file should be `/usr/local/var/mysql/charles.err`.

Answer (score 0):

know this is about 1 year old, but I found that when I try to start MYSQL (MariaDB 10) on my cluster master it launches fine, when the peers try to join with a Service MYSQL Start  (Centos6.6), I see the Starting MySQL that just puts the ..... for ever and never finishes. The cause of this according to the /var/lib/mysql/hostname.err file was that TCP over port 4567 was going out via multicast and was getting dropped by our network, so it never completes the mysql start process and hence never creates the PID file. Once we allowed the multicast packets, the process completed as expected and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can install mariadb again 
It should be related to removed or changed some mariadb file

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please provide more detailed answers for steps to debugging. See the other answers for examples.

Answer (score -1):

delete ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1

Comment: Instead of posting a second difficult to understand answer, can you please edit your original answer to include all the relevant details.